# Access VBA: Array values changing when record is changed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a piece of code that is meant to duplicate a record when executed but instead it is creating a blank record.

I have managed to track the bug to the array I was using to hold the field values from the old record. It seems that when `.AddNew` was run the array holding the values would change all its values to match this new record, in other words making them all `null` or `0`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
With rs1
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
        rs2.FindFirst "ItemID = " & !ItemID
        rs2.Edit
        rs2!ItemQuantity = rs2!ItemQuantity - !OrderQuantity
        TempArray = Array(rs2!ItemCode, rs2![Dia/Size], rs2!ItemType, rs2!Description, rs2!ItemAdded, rs2!ItemSaleValue, rs2!ItemBuyValue, rs2!ItemLocation, rs2!ItemCondition, rs2!ItemOrigin, rs2!ItemOriginDescription, rs2!ItemHistory)
        rs2.Update

        rs2.AddNew
        rs2!ItemCode = TempArray(0)
        rs2![Dia/Size] = TempArray(1)
        rs2!ItemType = TempArray(2)
        rs2!Description = TempArray(3)
        rs2!ItemAdded = TempArray(4)
        rs2!ItemSaleValue = TempArray(5)
        rs2!ItemBuyValue = TempArray(6)
        rs2!ItemLocation = TempArray(7)
        rs2!ItemCondition = TempArray(8)
        rs2!ItemOrigin = TempArray(9)
        rs2!ItemOriginDescription = TempArray(10)
        rs2!ItemHistory = TempArray(11)
        rs2!ItemBooked = True
        rs2!ItemBookedBy = Me.OrderBy
        rs2!ItemBookedWhen = Now()
        rs2!ItemBookedNote = Me.OrderID
        rs2.Update
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Here is where the record-sets reference to:

- rs1 is the items in the current order
- rs2 is the stock table/query

`TempArray` is the array I'm having trouble with so if someone could point out a way to stop it changing or a better way to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I also have `Option Explicit` at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake. You are adding the recordset's field objects to the array instead of the recordset field values.

Here is the code fix:

> ```
> TempArray = Array(rs2!ItemCode.Value, rs2![Dia/Size].Value, rs2!ItemType.Value, rs2!Description.Value, rs2!ItemAdded.Value, rs2!ItemSaleValue.Value, rs2!ItemBuyValue.Value, rs2!ItemLocation.Value, rs2!ItemCondition.Value, rs2!ItemOrigin.Value, rs2!ItemOriginDescription, rs2!ItemHistory.Value)
> ```

Comment: I'm using `DAO` in my database rather than `ADODB` fyi. In your answer where is rsClone getting its records from?

Comment: `DAO` also has a `Clone` property. [Recordset.Clone Method (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-clone-method-dao) - Creates a duplicate Recordset object that refers to the original Recordset object.

Comment: @Taazar Actually, Cloning wouldn't work because you are modifying the recordset.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. I went with the `.Value` solution anyway, it looked simpler. Thanks!